# SSRS Tablix filter parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a multi select parameter called unit with 3 values 15,16,17. I need to use these 3 values to filter 3 tables according to which unit was selected.

[image]

I was trying for the table's filter:

```
Expression: =Parameters!Units.Value
Operator: =
Value: 
=Parameters!Units.Value(0) --for the 1st table
=Parameters!Units.Value(1) --for the 2nd table
=Parameters!Units.Value(2) --for the 3rd table
```

However this always give me an error. It seemed the Expression part never work. Please help thanks!

Comment: Does =Parameters!Unites.Value(0) or (1) or (2) does return some value. I mean just try if it does return value. Also are you filtering Table I.e 3 different datasets or 3 Tablix?

Comment: Your parameter should relate to a field in your data - like Fields!Units.Value. Then you'd filter the data using an Operator of `IN` with a value of ` =Parameters!Units.Value `. For the separate tables, use a list to group by Units and put your table in it. The list will repeat the table for all Units selected by the parameter.

Comment: Thank you Hannover Fist I am trying that now.